# Token is not updated in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    include 'dbconn.php';
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id from users WHERE userEmail='$email'");

    if (!empty($sql) && $sql->num_rows > 0) {

        $token = "poiuytrewqlkjhgfdsamnbvcxz1234567890";
        $token = str_shuffle($token);
        $token = substr($token, 0, 10);

        $conn->query("UPDATE users SET token = '$token', 
                        tokenExpire = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) 
                        WHERE userEmail='$email'");

        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Please check your Email inbox!")));
    }
    else{
        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Please check your inputs!")));
    }
}?>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" align="center">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="300" height="300">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset password">
            <br>
            <p id="response"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var email = $('#email');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn-primary').on('click', function(){
            if(email.val() != ''){
                email.css('border', '1px solid green');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'forgotPassword.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        email: email.val()
                    }, success: function(response){
                        if (!response.success) {
                            $('#response').html(response.msg).css('color','red');
                        }else{
                            $('#response').html(response.msg).css('color','green');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                email.css('border', '1px solid red');
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

`tokenExpire` is updated in my db, but token is not only updated, also is not created in db. This is forgot password system through token and sending it to via mail, but I am doing only the beginning of this system.

Please help me cuz I am a beginner and cannot solve this problem for a long time.

Comment: Is there a language problem? "token is not only updated" means that the token *is* updated, but it's not the only thing that happened, and this phrase is usually followed by something additional that happened.

Comment: What do you mean by "not created in db"? Column creation happens when you create the table. If the column isn't created the query should get an error.

Comment: You should check the result of the query.

Comment: Please share your db schema, i can see your code working fine with my local setup. From the details you have given i assume your tokenExpire is updated and only token  is not getting updated in db. Please check the token field datatype. If everything looks correct then try to execute the query directly in mysql to see what you got as result

Answer (score 0):

Check the token field type, if its integer or Varchar. If its integer then convert to Varchar(255).